# Filter field in oracle

Tags: oracle

In table we have field for product code, we have 2 type of product codes

type 1) always starting with 2 number, then dash, then 5 number, then dash and at the end again 2 number. example is "12-04442-12"

type  2) always starting with 2 number, then dash, then 7 number, then dash and at the end again 2 number. example is "12-0993012-33"

we need get all records, when first 2 number (before dash) matchs last 2 number (after second dash) and code type is 2 (7 number between dashs).

from tthis

```
12-0993012-33
12-04442-12
07-0005402-07
12-00052-33
43-0010237-43
```

must resulted this

```
07-0005402-07
43-0010237-43
```

I am not so in database, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correct understand, your second type of code, always contains 13 character. If so, then use this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE
LENGTH(your_field) = 13 
AND 
SUBSTR(your_field, 1, 2) = SUBSTR(your_field, -2)
```